# Afghani Language

Tags: keyboard, language-support, internationalization

The official name of Afghan language is "DARI" but Ubuntu has listed it under "Afghani" in the input sources.

Please, Who should I contact to solve this issue...?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, سیف الله فضل. This could *probably* be considered a bug more than a feature request. [Follow these steps in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en) and hopefully someone can get it resolved in short order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog: Since this is an upstream matter, the guidance on how to report Ubuntu bugs does not help much.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson OK. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson even so, a bug should reported downstream as well so that Ubuntu devs can follow through and (if necessary) add a patch themselves

Comment: @muru: Well, yeah, that's how it generally works. In this particular case it simply won't happen that we would carry an Ubuntu specific patch for changing the name of a keyboard layout (which would also involve translations). So - in this case - a downstream bug would just be unnecessary paper work.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly there is a misconception. The keyboard layouts are often named after the countries where they are typically used rather than the language. So *Afghani* is consistent with how many other layouts are named, even if that keyboard layout is typically used for typing the Dari language.

If you still think it's wrong, please note that this is not an Ubuntu specific thing. Ubuntu uses the XKB data provided by freedesktop.org, and bugs should be reported here:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
There's a consistency for all other languages. But the word "Afghani" is never used as a language name at anytime for any country. (Afghani is the currency name of Afghanistan).
I'm a newbie in Linux and don't know who should I contact to report this.

Comment: @سیفاللهفضل: Just use the link I provided and report it as an issue.